# How to block user from opening pages if user is not logged in

Tags: python, django

I have login and  work page.
**I want user to login first and then redirect to work page. This scenario is working fine for me.**

However when I try hitting the work page it is giving me error, I am checking it through session variable which I know I am doing it wrong as I am not sure which user is trying to access the page if user tries to hit the work page directly as there will be many users in database.  How can I restrict user to hit the work page directly and if user does it should redirect to login page

views.py file method is as follows:-

```
def chatbox_index(request):
    context={}  
    template_name = "bot/chatbot.html"  
    **<I have to check here if user session is active or not?>**  
        return render(request, template_name,context=context)          
    else:  
        return render(request,'' ,context=context)
```

after user login I am creating session and storing in below 2 variables:-
**request.session['employee_name'] = employee.usrFirstName**
**request.session['employee_id'] = employee.id**

Comment: You don't need to store user details in the session. The user object is always available as `request.user`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django provides [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) decorator for this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def chatbox_index(request):
    context={}  
    template_name = "bot/chatbot.html"  
    return render(request, template_name,context=context)
```

Comment: @SohamKapoor  I saw your history of questions. You dont accept any answers that were correct. Do you have any problems related to it? I am sure we can help you out.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that but I'll keep this in mind from next time :) @SachinKukreja